Flutter web app is giving Exception when deployed to Firebase Hosting
I am working on a flutter web app and it is working fine, I also tried running release version of it and that is working too. But when I deployed it to firebase hosting(app is not giving any errors or warnings during deployment and after successfull deployment) when I am trying to visit the web app with the given url by the firebase deploy --only hosting command. I am getting the following Exceptions

Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: https://liquid-canvas.web.app/icons/Icon-192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)Understand this errormain.dart.js:38305 Rejecting promise with error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON$1 @ main.dart.js:38305Understand this warningliquid-canvas.web.app/:1 Uncaught (in

This is my index.html content:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="lqdcnvd_content_partner_panel">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>lqdcnvd_content_partner_panel</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
</body>
</html>


firebase.json content is:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

I run the web app in release version with the following command and is working fine:

flutter run --release

here is the url on which i deployed the app
https://liquid-canvas.web.app/

From what I can quickly see the URL is giving back an HTML response, but you really should check this in your browser's developer tools yourself. If that is indeed happening, it might be that your firebase.json (which determines the behavior of Firebase Hosting) is configured to redirect all URLs to the main (HTML) page as shown in the documentation on rewrites. If so, you'll want to remove that rewrite configuration so that it serves the files at the requested path.
Note that I had to make a lot of assumptions here, so I recommend reading how to ask a good question and how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example going forward to make it more likely that we can help without having to assume so much (which also makes posts much more useful for future visitors).

I have added firebase.json and index.html content. this working fine when I run it from vscode in  browser but after deployment it is giving this issue.
